# Best Practise for executing Something in Background in custom module

Tags: 7

I have written a custom module which creates a link on the page.

When you clicking the link

```
<a href="path_to_module/lib/script.php?lotOfparameters=value>
  Do it
</a>
```

a php file is called, where all the logic of the module is done (create a node with predefined field values, create a pane for panels module and other stuff).

But i think this isn´t the recommend way to to this in Drupal. Doing this in the .php file is tooking sometimes a lot of time, so a progress bar would be nice for exmaple.

So I am looking for the best way to do logic when a button is clicked on the site.

**EDIT:** 
I think that was a bad description for my problem, so i try to make this better.

In my Templates, e.g. page.tpl.php and node.tpl.php, I´m printing a link to create a button. If the buttons gets clicked I want to do some stuff, i think what exactly is irrelevant. But I'm doing this with a direct link to a .php file in the link. In this .php file all things are executed. And I think THIS isnt the best way to do things in drupal.

Comment: While this link (https://drupal.org/node/102338) is for Drupal 6, it gives a great overview of Drupal's menu system and callbacks and so forth that detail how (IMHO) you should set up logic for when a button/link is clicked on your site.

Comment: There's so many problems with the approach to solution here, that it's hard to know where to begin. Scrap everything, and start reading from the link Jimajamma gave you.

Answer (score 3):

Extremely broad question, so an extremely broad answer...

Use the [Batch API](https://drupal.org/node/180528).

If you need more code examples than the docs page provides, the [examples module](https://drupal.org/project/examples) has a lot of good, related code.

Answer (score 0):

What @Clive said -- that's the best way to execute a long process in manageable chunks -- but if you also want to kick this off in the background without reloading the page, you'll want to use the [Ajax framework](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!ajax.inc/group/ajax/7) to execute it.